# List all wiki pages on wiki `Home` page

Tags: github

I'm looking for a way to list all pages on the wiki `Home` page instead of the standard welcome message. Here's an example of what I want:
https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki

Comment: I have similar question about bitbucket. Have you found the correct answer ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it! The trick was to delete the `Home` page, but it was impossible to do directly from github.

Here's a workaround: Go to `wiki` / `Git Access` and clone the wiki repository with the provided link. In the cloned repo just delete the file representing the `Home` page (in my case it was `Home.md`). Push the changes back.

Comment: the best way is to create a new wiki page, then change the page title to home.. easy! credit to @owahab

Comment: So when you go to the wiki (via the sidebar link) to which page you land ?

Answer (score 7):

As of at least July 2014, none of these suggestions work anymore. They will seem to work at first, and you'll get the page full of links as your homepage, but only temporarily. Regardless of how you delete or rename the Home page, it will be auto-created again the next time you make edits to the wiki.

Comment: thanks Toby, i did notice that. Is there a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: @AhmadAssaf none that I have found.. but they seem to be constantly updating the site so hopefully it returns before long

Answer (score 5):

I just went to `Home` page (something like https://github.com/user/repo/wiki), then clicked `Edit page` and then `Delete page`.

*And one important thing*: if you deleted `Home` page and want to get it back — just create a new page with name `Home`.

Comment: I tried this, page would refresh after Delete, but then still existed. Perhaps Github glitch, or intentional, dunno.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to delete the home page with `git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/ORG/REPO.wiki.git
cd REPO.wiki
rm Home.md
git add .
git commit -m "remove wiki homepage"
git push
```

**Update**: GitHub automatically added a `Initial Home page` commit that reset created a `Home.md`. So my alternative is generating the Home page myself:

- `git push`
- Create a `Home.rb` file with this content:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby
  File.write('Home.md', Dir['*.md'].reject { |f| f == "Home.md" }.map { |f|
    "- [#{f.gsub('.md', '').gsub(/-+/, ' ')}](#{f.gsub('.md', '')})"
  }.join("\n"))
  ```
- `ruby Home.rb`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "generated home page"`
- `git push`

Comment: @GrantWinney It generates a Home.md file that I update with the script every one in a while

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured out how to do it: Go to Home page > click Edit page > Delete the title and content > Click save. Done, you will see something like https://github.com/host-gator/t/wiki

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more. Worse, GH now creates a default home page even if you delete one.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this. The `delete page` option is not available whilst the page is called `Home`. But if you amend it to something else like `home_old`, you can then edit it again and you have access to the `Delete Page` option. You then have the automatic index page without a redundant `Home` page.

Comment: Looks like GitHub re-creates the Home page after a moment :(